# Combine relation with custom SQL

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'd like to generate the following SQL with rails / arel:

```
SELECT * FROM GROUPS
WHERE id = 10
CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = ID
```

I don't want to use plain SQL except for the last statement which is oracle specific (the real query is much more complex and I don't want to perform endless string concatenations).

What I've tried so far:

```
Group.where(id: 10).join('CONNECT BY PARENT_ID=ID')
```

This does not work as it places the custom SQL **before** the `WHERE` statement (as it assumes it's a join).

So the actual question is, how to add a custom bit of SQL to a query **after** the `WHERE` statements?

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Nope, Oracle. But this is a generic question and should apply to every DBMS using SQL.